# Flask-socketio instance not Emitting from an External Process (Django)

Tags: django, python-3.x, redis, socket.io, flask-socketio

Hello am trying to emit to flask-socketIO from an external python application (django) but unfortunately it is not emitting.

I have defined my flask-socket app as follows:

```
app.register_blueprint(views)
socketio.init_app(app, message_queue='redis://127.0.0.1:6380')
```

My views are as follows:

```
from flask import render_template
from .. import socketio
from App import socketio
from App.views import views
from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room, emit
import cgi


def ack():
    print("cron_failedMsg was delivered")


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/node/cron')
def ws_conn():
    print("Connected")


@socketio.on('join', namespace='/node/cron')
def on_join(data):
    print("Joined room " + data['room'])
    join_room("room_" + data['room'])
    emit('msg', {'msg': "joined room room_" +
                 data['room']}, room="room_" + data['room'])


@socketio.on('leave', namespace='/node/cron')
def on_leave(data):
    print("leaved")
    leave_room("room_" + data['room'])

@socketio.on('cron_failed', namespace='/node/cron')
def ws_cron_failed(message):
    print("Failed")
    print("sending to room " + message['room'])
    """
    socketio.emit('cron_failed', {
                  'cron_failed': cgi.escape(message['cron_failed'])}, namespace='/node/cron')
    """
    emit('cron_failedMsg', {
        'cron_failed': cgi.escape(message['cron_failed'])}, room="room_" + cgi.escape(message['room']))
```

Am emitting to the message queue from an external python application (Django):

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://' +
                            redis6380_conf.redis6380['host'] + ":" + redis6380_conf.redis6380['port'])
        socketio.emit(
            'cron_' + status, {'cron' + status: redisConnection6381.get(str(userID) + '_' + status), 'room': str(userID)}, namespace='/node/cron')
```

Unfortunately its not emitting from the external python process.

I've tested emission from a webpage using javascript it works but not from the external python application(Django):

```
var url = "http://" + document.domain + ":" + location.port;
var socket = io.connect(url + "/node/cron");
socket.emit('join',{room:""+$rootScope.Data.ID});
 socket.emit('cron_failed',{cron_failed:"ddd",room:"3"})
```

How do I emit from the external python application(Django)? Is there any issue with the way am emitting from the external process?

For info I followed the instructions: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to emit from the Django process to the Flask-SocketIO server? If that's what you want to do, then on the Django side you need to use a Socket.IO client. For example, this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client.

The "emit from an external process" feature of Flask-SocketIO is different. The idea is that you want several server processes to emit to the client. This feature allows the Django server to emit to the client through the Flask-SocketIO server.

From your example, it seems you were expecting the `'cron_failed'` event in your Flask-SocketIO server to run when you emit from Django, but really what you are doing is sending the event of that name to the clients. Maybe what you want is to change the event name to `'cron_failedMsg'` on the Django emit? That's what the client expects, it seems.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Using `socketIO-client` with defined `namespace` worked for me :)